# Gravar múltiplas imagens através de um bloco Gutenberg WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Estou a criar um novo bloco de `Gutenberg` que serve como galeria de imagens.
A ideia é o utilizador conseguir carregar diversas imagens através do back-office.

Para os atributos tenho o seguinte:

```
    attributes: {
        imgURL: {
            type: 'string',
            source: 'attribute',
            attribute: 'src',
            selector: 'img'
        },
    },
```

Dentro do Edit:

```
edit: function( props ) {

        const onFileSelect = (img) => {

            props.setAttributes({

                imgURL: img.url,
                imgID: img.id,
                imgAlt: img.alt

            });
        }
(...)
<MediaUpload
                            onSelect={onFileSelect}
                            value={1}
                            render= {({open}) =>
                                <Button
                                    onClick={open}
                                >
                                    Load image
                                </Button>
                            }
                        />
```

Para uma imagem funciona bem mas eu queria que o código fosse dinâmico. 
Qual será a melhor abordagem ?

Comment: se a resposta está certa, n te esqueças de marcar como certa @joão-dessain-saraiva

Answer (score 0):

Tens que criar uma função que recolha todos os ids da galeria.

Deixo-te aqui um control que podes usar, o nome que dei ao attr foi de gallery, tens que o defenir antes do return dentro do metodo render()

```
<MediaUpload
onSelect={( images ) => {
    const imagesList = images.map( ( image ) => {
        return {
            id: image.id,
            url: image.url
        };
    } );
    this.props.setAttributes( { gallery: JSON.stringify( imagesList ) } );
}}
allowedTypes={['image']}
value={gallery !== '' ? gallery.map( ( image ) => image.id ) : ''}
multiple
gallery
render={( { open } ) => (
    <IconButton
        label={__( 'Alterar Gallery' )}
        icon="format-image"
        onClick={open}
    />
)} />
```

O codigo do attributes:

```
'gallery' => [
    'type'    => 'string',
    'default' => '',
],
```